# ForgeGradle actions causing IntelliJ to crash

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

The gradle process fails when I tried to build or sync my Forge mod written in Kotlin with IntelliJ
The way to find any output is from the logs:

```
[  34623]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.g.p.s.GradleSyncState - No error message given
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No error message given
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncFailed(GradleSyncState.kt:235)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.access$syncFailed(GradleSyncState.kt:88)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState$SyncStateUpdater.onEvent(GradleSyncState.kt:506)
    at com.intellij.build.AbstractViewManager.onEvent(AbstractViewManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher$onEvent$1.accept(AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher.kt:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher$onEvent$1.accept(AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher.kt:14)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher$close$1.accept(AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.execution.AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher$close$1.accept(AbstractOutputMessageDispatcher.kt:14)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at com.intellij.build.output.BuildOutputInstantReaderImpl$readerRunnable$1.run(BuildOutputInstantReaderImpl.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.lambda$underThreadNameRunnable$3(ConcurrencyUtil.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I am on the latest version of ubuntu, and have tried deleting the .gradle folder, invalidating caches, and re-downloading the project.

Thank You for helping

Comment: `com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncFailed` is it an Android project? Can you build by Gradle from the command line? Need a sample project to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, I had my system java version set to java 17, rather than java 8. after I changed the alternate and deleted my .gradle folder it worked